# C#: RestClient: RestRequest fails for lower case header

Tags: c#, rest, rest-client

I have the code below in c#, which uses RestClient. The issue is that the headers should not be case-sensitive but looks like they are.

```
var client = new RestClient(sMA_URL);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

//Without the line below the RestRequest adds some default header which is not acceptable by our server. 
 request.AddHeader("**Accept**", "*/*");
 request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
 request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer "+sBearerToken);

// Make sure you deserialize this response, for further use. The best way to do this is to create a class and then fill that with the values obtained by the response but if a response is not used many times,
// you can do it the way it has been done in Bearer Token Generation

 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

 Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

When I give accept (in lower case) it complains about the content-type but Accept (upper case) works fine.No, error regarding the content-type. I can't figure out if the issue is with the service it's trying to call or with RestClient itself.

This is the status code I get (No exception)
'NotAcceptable Content-Type'

Comment: are you getting any exception or could you show us the response message and code ?

Comment: Added the return status

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is included in the response, its self explanatory.

> "NotAcceptable Content-Type"

The message above means that the api, service or endpoint your are trying sending your request to, rejects your request based on the `content-type` header which is '`application/json`'.

Since you are sending a **GET** request, i don't see why do you need to specify `content-type` at all.

Try removing the `content-type` header and probably your request will work.

Adding the `content-type` header would be used for **POST** or **PUT** requests, where you are sending a body/payload in the request (example: json,form data,xml,multipart,etc...), and even for this type of requests it is still not mandatory unless the server you are sending your requests to requires you to specify the `content-type`.

Comment: The issue is when I give Accept header in lower case, it complains about the content- type but when I give Aceept (in upper case) it doesn't. I want to know if the issue is with the service I'm calling or RestClient.  I can't remove it altogether because it has been a part of the code since a long time.

Comment: I would assume that it failed to read that header and swallowed any exception it threw.

Comment: If you are trying to isolate the reason, take your client out of the equation and use fiddler or postman.  If you still get the exception exception it is the service.